Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Insufficient balance'
contract functions
function depositEarnest(uint nftId,bool rent) public payable
    {
        require(isListed[nftId],"Property is already sold");
        require(tenant[nftId]==address(0),"Property is on Rent");
        if(!rent)
            require(msg.value>=escrowAmount[nftId],"Amount should be greater than/equal to  escrow amount");
        else
        {
           require(msg.value>=priceForRent[nftId],"Amount should be greater than/equal to  escrow amount"); 
           tenant[nftId]=msg.sender;
        }
    }

    function approveSale(uint nftId) public {
        require(approval[nftId][msg.sender]==false,"ALready Approved");
        approval[nftId][msg.sender]=true;

    }

    function executeBuying(uint nftId) public {
        uint supply =  getTotalSupply();
        require(nftId<=supply,"Property doesn't exists");
        require(isInspectionPassed[nftId]==true,"Inspection Isn't passed");
        require(address(this).balance>=priceForBuy[nftId],"Insufficient balance");

        address seller = sellers[nftId];
        uint amount = escrowAmount[nftId];
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance in escrow contract");

        isListed[nftId]=false;
        (bool success,)=payable(seller).call{value:amount}("Amount transfered");
        PTKcontract.transferFrom(address(this),msg.sender,nftId);
        require(success,"Transfer to seller failed");
        emit PurchaisedPropertySuccess(nftId,msg.sender,seller);

    }


test script
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const { time } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");

describe("Escrow", function () {
  let Escrow;
  let escrow;
  let PropertyToken;
  let propertyToken;
  let owner;
  let inspector;
  let seller;
  let buyer;
  let tenant;

  const TOKEN_ID = 1;
  const PRICE_FOR_RENT = ethers.parseEther("0.1");
  const PRICE_FOR_BUY = ethers.parseEther("1");
  const ESCROW_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.5");

  beforeEach(async function () {
    [owner, inspector, seller, buyer, tenant] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // Deploy PropertyToken
    PropertyToken = await ethers.getContractFactory("PropertyToken");
    propertyToken = await PropertyToken.deploy(owner.address);
    await propertyToken.waitForDeployment();

    // Deploy Escrow
    Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory("Escrow");
    escrow = await Escrow.deploy(await propertyToken.getAddress(), inspector.address);
    await escrow.waitForDeployment();

    // Mint a token to the seller
    await propertyToken.connect(owner).safeMint(seller.address, "https://example.com/token/1");
    await propertyToken.connect(seller).approve(await escrow.getAddress(), TOKEN_ID);
  });

  describe("Deployment", function () {
    it("Should set the right PTK address", async function () {
      expect(await escrow.PTKaddress()).to.equal(await propertyToken.getAddress());
    });

    it("Should set the right inspector", async function () {
      expect(await escrow.inspector()).to.equal(inspector.address);
    });
  });

  describe("Listing Property", function () {
    it("Should list a property", async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      expect(await escrow.getSeller(TOKEN_ID)).to.equal(seller.address);
    });

    it("Should not allow listing with zero prices", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, 0, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT)).to.be.revertedWith("Enter a Amount greater than 0");
      await expect(escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, 0, ESCROW_AMOUNT)).to.be.revertedWith("Enter a Amount greater than 0");
    });
  });

  describe("Depositing Earnest", function () {
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
    });

    it("Should allow depositing earnest for buying", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID, false, { value: ESCROW_AMOUNT }))
        .to.not.be.reverted;
    });

    it("Should allow depositing earnest for renting", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(tenant).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID, true, { value: PRICE_FOR_RENT }))
        .to.not.be.reverted;
    });

    it("Should not allow depositing if property is not listed", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID + 1, false, { value: ESCROW_AMOUNT }))
        .to.be.revertedWith("Property is already sold");
    });
  });

  describe("Executing Buy", function () {
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID, false, { value: ESCROW_AMOUNT });
      await escrow.connect(inspector).approveInspection(TOKEN_ID);
      await propertyToken.connect(seller).transferFrom(seller.address, await escrow.getAddress(), TOKEN_ID);
      // await buyer.sendTransaction({
      //   to: await escrow.getAddress(),
      //   value: PRICE_FOR_BUY
      // });
    });

    it("Should execute buying", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(buyer).executeBuying(TOKEN_ID))
        .to.emit(escrow, "PurchaisedPropertySuccess")
        .withArgs(TOKEN_ID, buyer.address, seller.address);
    });

    it("Should not allow buying without inspection", async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID + 1, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      await escrow.connect(buyer).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID + 1, false, { value: ESCROW_AMOUNT });
      await expect(escrow.connect(buyer).executeBuying(TOKEN_ID + 1))
        .to.be.revertedWith("Inspection Isn't passed");
    });
  });

  describe("Executing Rent", function () {
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      await escrow.connect(tenant).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID, true, { value: PRICE_FOR_RENT });
      await escrow.connect(inspector).approveInspection(TOKEN_ID);
    });

    it("Should execute renting", async function () {
      await expect(escrow.connect(tenant).executeRent(TOKEN_ID, 7))
        .to.emit(escrow, "RentedPropertySuccess")
        .withArgs(TOKEN_ID, tenant.address, seller.address, 2);  // 2 is rentForweek
    });

    it("Should not allow renting without earnest", async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID + 1, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      await escrow.connect(inspector).approveInspection(TOKEN_ID + 1);
      await expect(escrow.connect(tenant).executeRent(TOKEN_ID + 1, 7))
        .to.be.revertedWith("Have to deposit Earnest first");
    });
  });

  describe("Chainlink Automation", function () {
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await escrow.connect(seller).listProperty(TOKEN_ID, PRICE_FOR_RENT, PRICE_FOR_BUY, ESCROW_AMOUNT);
      await escrow.connect(tenant).depositEarnest(TOKEN_ID, true, { value: PRICE_FOR_RENT });
      await escrow.connect(inspector).approveInspection(TOKEN_ID);
      await escrow.connect(tenant).executeRent(TOKEN_ID, 7);
    });

    it("Should check upkeep", async function () {
      await time.increase(8 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // Increase time by 8 days
      const [upkeepNeeded, performData] = await escrow.checkUpkeep("0x");
      expect(upkeepNeeded).to.be.true;
    });

    it("Should perform upkeep", async function () {
      await time.increase(8 * 24 * 60 * 60);  // Increase time by 8 days
      const [, performData] = await escrow.checkUpkeep("0x");
      await expect(escrow.performUpkeep(performData))
        .to.emit(escrow, "returnRentedProperty");
    });

    it("Should not need upkeep before rental period ends", async function () {
      const [upkeepNeeded, ] = await escrow.checkUpkeep("0x");
      expect(upkeepNeeded).to.be.false;
    });
  });
});

test result
 Deployment
      ✔ Should set the right PTK address
      ✔ Should set the right inspector
    Listing Property
      ✔ Should list a property
      ✔ Should not allow listing with zero prices
    Depositing Earnest
      ✔ Should allow depositing earnest for buying
      ✔ Should allow depositing earnest for renting
      ✔ Should not allow depositing if property is not listed
    Executing Buy
      1) Should execute buying
      2) Should not allow buying without inspection
    Executing Rent
      3) Should execute renting
      4) Should not allow renting without earnest
    Chainlink Automation
      5) "before each" hook for "Should check upkeep"

1) Escrow
       Executing Buy
         Should execute buying:
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Insufficient balance'


Question:
The escrowAmount is deposited to the smart contract while running depositEarnest. That same amount it has to transfer to the seller. Is the error causing because of the gas needed for tx?
How to handle it?

Can you share your code via GitHub repo, so that I can try to debug on my end?

https://github.com/dev-soumyadeep/CryptoEstate

You're facing the Insufficient balance error because of the failing of this require condition in the executeBuying function of your Escrow contract:
require(address(this).balance >= priceForBuy[nftId], "Insufficient balance");

And, the reason for that, is:
In the beforeEach of "Executing Buy" section of your test, you're calling listProperty by passing in the PRICE_FOR_BUY as 1 ether and ESCROW_AMOUNT as 0.5 ether, as defined in the starting of the file, i.e.,
const PRICE_FOR_BUY = ethers.parseEther("1");
const ESCROW_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.5");

But, according to the logic, the ESCROW_AMOUNT should be greater than or equal to PRICE_FOR_BUY.
So, you can either make ESCROW_AMOUNT as 1 ether or more, like:
const PRICE_FOR_BUY = ethers.parseEther("1");
const ESCROW_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("1");

Or, you can make PRICE_FOR_BUY as 0.5 ether or less, like:
const PRICE_FOR_BUY = ethers.parseEther("0.5");
const ESCROW_AMOUNT = ethers.parseEther("0.5");

